# Move the caret to proper indentation inside insert mode in C files when using arrow keys

Tags: indentation, filetype-c

In insert mode, scope indentation is not taken into account if I navigate rows during insert mode. Example:

[image]

In such a case, if I would press the up arrow key, Vim would place my caret at the start of the 19th line:

[image]

But I would instead prefer:

[image]

What can I do to have this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason arrow keys don't indent is the indentation does not actually exist and is not created on movement.
Instead, use normal mode.

Rather than pressing arrow keys, press <kbd>O</kbd> to make a new line.

Alternatively, on the new line, press <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>